# Cutting the string if its too long an saving the original in Python 2.7.2

Tags: python

I want to be able to calculate the string lenght including blancs between words and if it exceeds 100 char I have to cut it. Here is an example of string:

```
'The string99 blah, 2-blahh,........blahhhhhh'
```

I don't want to cut words, so if 100 chars come in the middle of the word I need to go back at the end of the prevous word. The last blanc and comma must be removed.
The original string must be saved as a text file and the name of the file must be the cut string.

Any help?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.  We are here to help fix what you have not do your work for you.

Comment: I'm an amateur. I'm old enough to not be interested in learning Python in perfection. I'm interested in solving a specific problem. I've started using Python a week for now. Unfortunately it is not an intuitive language for me at all. From the other hand there are a lot of young people here eager to hone their skills in Python. So what is wrong asking to solve a small specific problem for me?

Comment: @Ash When you hover over the downvote button on Stack Overflow, you see the following text: "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful." If you don't make an attempt to solve your problem on your own first, you (1) won't learn anything, and (2) will get your question downvoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I probably misunderstood what you were asking, but what I took your question to mean was that you wanted to do the following:

- If the string was longer than 100 characters, remove the last comma and/or space.
- Then, truncate the string into 100 characters.
- If the truncation occurred in the body of a word, truncate the string further to remove the last word fragment.
- Finally, create a text file with the truncated string as its filename, and write the original string to that file.

I assume that if you didn't cut the string, you wanted to name the file the same thing as the original string... also, that you had only one string... you weren't very clear, though, so I may be assuming wrong. Anyway, here you are:

```
the_string = "this is a very long string, here is a very long word, f" + ("o" * 50) + " good bye, string, "
filename_string = the_string
if len(the_string) > 100:  
    # if the 100th character is not a space or a comma
    if the_string[99] != " " and the_string[99] != ",":
        # split the string by words, and rejoin all but the last
        # if it ends with a comma, remove it (it won't end in a space because of split())
        filename_string = " ".join(stripped_string[:99].split()[:-1]).rstrip(",")
    else:
        # just remove the last space (and if there is one, a comma)
        filename_string = stripped_string[:100].rstrip(", ")
with open(filename_string, 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(the_string)
```

Upon running, I got a file named `this is a very long string, here is a very long word` and its contents were `this is a very long string, here is a very long word foooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo good bye, string,`. (There was a space at the end but SO doesn't show it.) As you can see, I didn't cut in the middle of "fooooooo" etc., and the filename didn't end with a comma or a space.

If you want to do this for any old string, well, change `the_string`... or you can use `raw_input()` to get user input for it... or you can use the `argparse` module to get command-line arguments. You do the research to figure out how to do it.

Comment: Thank you very much 2rs2ts for the detailed answer and explanation. I didn't try it yet, but even if they are small problems I can fix them myself.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`textwrap`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html) module:

**Demo:**

```
>>> import textwrap
>>> strs = "foo bar spam eggs "*10
>>> for x in textwrap.wrap(strs, 15):
    print x
...     
foo bar spam
eggs foo bar
spam eggs foo
bar spam eggs
foo bar spam
eggs foo bar
spam eggs foo
bar spam eggs
foo bar spam
eggs foo bar
spam eggs foo
bar spam eggs
foo bar spam
eggs
```